# Simulate slow HTTP connect for Java integration test?

Tags: java, web-services, http, servlets, jax-ws

is it possible to simulate a slow HTTP connect in a Java integration test, so that I can define how long the server should wait until he confirms the connection? A solution which also supports a JAX-WS webservice would be perfect.

***Background:***
I have to integration test a central timeout configurator. The configurator itself must be technology-independent. At first it supports JAX-WS webservices, therefore the attribute `com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout` will be set in request context.

(I'll try to convince them, that it is part of JAX-WS and thus we don't need to test it, but this question is my backup plan.)

*P.S.: There are other questions which ask about simulating a slow connection in general. This is different because I cannot use external tools in an unit test and I must be able to define a specific connection time.*

Comment: I would recommend using EasyMock. It's not as easy as the name implies, but it does make testing things like http connections and databases much easier.

Comment: @JREN: I know EasyMock, but how can I simulate a slow connect with it? The connection is created by JAX-WS, so it's difficult to inject a mock, isn't it?

Comment: What we usually do is create a protected method called currentMillis in our class which returns System.currentTimeMillis() so that we can override it to return a field variable in our test class to simulate time skips of however long we like by simply adding time to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my unit test, I used NanoHTTPd https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd which is a pure Java. It is only one class.

Comment: Great! I only had to modify NanoHTTPD#start() so that it calls a custom method for creating a ServerSocket and then I overwrote ServerSocket#accept() to sleep for a given time before calling it's super implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through a proxy (http or socks) which can be embedded in your application.  You can then tell the proxy to provide the behavior you need to test.

I had to test a dropped TCP/IP connection ([How to reproduce a silently dropped TCP/IP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6116382/53897)) and ended up going through a SOCKS proxy written in Java, which I just suspended to emulate the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, a proxy would be fine, but how do I implement it? I'm only familiar with servlet programming, and servlets don't handle the connection themselves.

Comment: JAX-WS runs below what you can handle with from a web application, you need better integration in the application server itself.  You need to set system properties when launching the application server JVM in order to redirect http traffic.  I suggest you add more information about your environment and what _you_ have the power to do to your question.  Things like what server you use is quite relevant.